# How can I use perl one liner to split one line in to multiple using regex?

Tags: perl

How can I split a line in to multiple lines using a Perl one-liner?

Input:

```
AAAA | BBBB | CCCCCCCCCCC | 19999AAA | AAA
```

Output:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCCCCCCCCC
19999AAA
AAA
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Do you just want to replace the vertical bar character with newlines?  ie. `s/\|/\n/g`?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to replace the whitespace and pipe delimiter with a line break.

```
echo "your input" | perl -pe 's/\s*\|\s*/\n/g'
```

You can perform a split here and join your strings.

```
echo "your input" | perl -ne 'print join("\n", split /\s*\|\s*/, $_)'
```

Comment: Your last solution doesn't kill all spaces. And it really is way too complicated.

Comment: Your answer while complicated helped me to fix my join-split one-liner...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for a one-liner, I suppose you're not trying to put this in an existing perl script, so why not use a plain shell command for this:

```
tr -s '| ' '[\n*]'
```

This replaces any sequence of characters in the first set into a newline. The peculiar syntax `[\n*]` makes sure this works with any POSIX-compliant `tr`. With GNU or BSD `tr`, this simpler syntax should also work:

```
tr -s '| ' '\n'
```

Pretty much the same can be done with Perl proper:

```
perl -pe 'tr/ |/\n/s'
```

Answer (score -1):

Using something like one of those:

```
perl -pe 's/ \| /\n/g'
perl -nE 'say for split / \| /'
```

Comment: always use // for the first parameter of split (except for the special case of `split ' '`) so you don't forget it's always a regex.  your split fails.

Comment: You need to backslash the pipe in both examples.

Comment: That's what I deserve for posting untested from mobile :-) Thanks both, I edited.